# Accessing Ajax Response Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have this code that works well:

```
{"livre":"empty_name"}

    $.ajax({
        url: "sent.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: formdata,
        success: function (data) {
            switch (data.livre) {
                  case 'empty_name':

                  break;
        }
    });
```

but when i try this code (i need the id), the case "empty name" didn't works. The option selected will be the default case:

```
{"id":"","livre":"empty_name"}

    $.ajax({
        url: "sent.php",
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        data: formdata,
        success: function (id, data) {
            switch (data.livre) {
                 case 'empty_name':

                 break;
        }
    });
```

Why? and how can be solved? thanks

Comment: You sure you don't have a JavaScript error. Your switch syntax looks wrong - errand `});`

Comment: Install Fiddler, it will help you massively to debug your problem. It shows a list of requests including your ajax ones, and your responses.

Comment: I think he is giving us minimal code, not wrong code.  Try using data['livre'] instead...?  I don't really see the problem, I'm just hoping...

Comment: Why do you have 'id' in your callback function?

Comment: data.id and data.livre is what i need. thanks for help

Comment: In your second example, just remove the id parameter from the callback function.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If I understand correctly with the object up top being the JSON response, I think you want this...

```
{"id":"","livre":"empty_name"}

$.ajax({
    url: "sent.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formdata,
    success: function (data) {
        var jsonId = data.id;
    }
});
```

The `data` parameter of the `success` callback contains your response (in this case, JSON data). You access your JSON content there.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to understand how the data is being returned. In this case `data` is the object containing all the fields. Your success callback would continue to look like `success: function(data)` the code you need to change is in the method block itself.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "sent.php",
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    data: formdata,
    success: function (data) {
        var id = data.id; //ID lives in data.
        switch (data.livre) {
    }
});
```

Since you redefined the function, the switch will fail because in the example posted `livre` will reside in the `id` object and *not* in the `data` object.